# How to display asp button text into multiple lines?

Tags: c#, html, button

I have a button which displays text in my C#.

```html
<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="roundBtns" type="button" runat="server" />
```

My C# snippet looks something like

```
String Item;  //getting  from the user
String Quantity;  //getting from the user

Button1.Text = Item + " " + Quantity;
```

I want the Item and Quantity to be in different lines inside the button.
I have tried the following:

1. System.Environment.Newline = no effect
2. "< br />" = prints "< br />" in between texts
3. "\n" in place of " "  = no effect
4. Set my white-space:normal

None of these seem to work. I can’t set padding to a certain width to force the second string to another line either  because I don’t know how long a user might enter. All I need is the two different strings in two separate lines.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to do this using `Environment.Newline` or `&#13;&#10;` but I don't think it is with modern web browsers. There are a couple of options you could use:

1) Use a LinkButton and style it to look like a standard button

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="Button1">
  Your <br/> text
</asp:LinkButton>
```

2) Use an html button as a server control

```
<button runat="server" id="Button1">
  Your <br/> text
</button>
```

You could put an `asp:Literal` control inside the parent control to make the text settable on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this:
style="white-space: break-spaces;"